# Upload multiple files using multipart/form-data and fetch in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, fetch, multipartform-data, form-data

I have worked on uploading a single file using form-data and fetch (POST request). But, I am getting an issue with uploading multiple files. Below is my code:

HTML Part of vue.js:

```
<el-button @click="post_visible = true">POST</el-button>
      <el-dialog :visible.sync="post_visible" title="Adding a new value!"> 
                    <span>Image_1</span>
                    <input type="file" name="file1" />
                    <br>
                    <br>

                    <span>Image_2</span>
                    <input type="file" name="file2" />
                    <br>
                    <br>

                    <span>Image_3</span>
                    <input type="file" name="file3" />
                    <br>
                    <br>

                    <el-button @click = "submit"> Submit </el-button>

      </el-dialog>
```

Javascript part:

```
methods:{
submit(){

 var formData = new FormData();
 var fileField = document.querySelector("input[type='file']");

 console.log(fileField.files.length) // printing the length of the fileField.files. 

// attaching the files.
 formData.append('file', fileField.files[0]); 
 formData.append('file', fileField.files[1]); 
 formData.append('file', fileField.files[2]); 

const headers = new Headers();
            
headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer '+ token); // tokenhas been initialized

const body = formData;
const init = {
method: 'POST',
headers,
body
};

fetch('http://*********/****', init)
.then((response) => {
return response.json(); // or .text() or .blob() ...
  })
 .then((text) => {
  // text is the response body
 })
  .catch((e) => {
// error in e.message
  });
}
}
```

I get 500 error(which is an internal server error). There is no issue with the server as I managed to do a successful (200) post request to the api using the tool 'AdvancedRestClient'. I have realized that the issue is with uploading the files. As I printed out the length of the fileField.files and it comes out to be 1. It should have been 3, but I get only 1. Also, I see on the webpage (after inspecting the webpage), that the formdata object has taken in only 1 file and the values for the other two files in undefined. This means that I messed up something in the code to upload multiple files. Any help to identify my mistake or any other alternative solution would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Yes,. `fileField[0].files[0]` ,. `fileField[1].files[0]`. As your not using a single input with `multiple` but multiple inputs instead..  Also you will want `querySelectorAll` as you have 3 inputs not just 1.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But your above solution did not work.

Answer (score 0):

you only getting one element because of the used selector.

Instead of [document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) you should use [document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

But be aware that `document.querySelectorAll` returns a list/array of nodes and then you must change how you access the files.

Regards
Simon

Hint:
Please use `let` instead of `var`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But your above solution is giving the following error (while trying to print the length of the fileField.files). 

TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

I removed console.log and tried ot again and the error shifts to TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

This means that document.querySelectorAll does not return anything. Basically, fileField is empty and hence, it gives the above errors. Please could you give me some other solution? I changed var to let as well and it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the above issue. Made some code changes. Instead of using  document.querySelector, I used document.getElementById('file1'). I made some changes in the html file and the javascript code. This is not an ideal way or an efficient way to solve the problem, but for now I have a working solution.

changes in In html part of the vue.js is that "name" field is changed to "id" field.

```
                    <span>Image_1</span>
                    <input type="file" id="file1" />
                    <br>
                    <br>

                    <span>Image_2</span>
                    <input type="file" id="file2" />
                    <br>
                    <br>

                    <span>Image_3</span>
                    <input type="file" id="file3" />
                    <br>
                    <br>
```

Changes in the javascript file: Instead of document.querySelector I used document.getElementById.

```
var formData = new FormData();
            
const fileField1 = document.getElementById('file1')
const fileField2 = document.getElementById('file2')
const fileField3 = document.getElementById('file3')

formData.append('file', fileField1.files[0]); // attaching the file
formData.append('file', fileField2.files[0]); // attaching the file
formData.append('file', fileField3.files[0]); // attaching the file

// the code for headers, fetch and POST reamins the same.
```

You can also do this with document.getElementByName. I just like id more(personal choice).

This solution worked for me. Not a perfect way to solve the issue as it would make the code ugly and tedious to write if there are tons of files to upload, but for now solves my issue.

Would appreciate if someone gave an efficient solution to this problem.

Comment: Yes, `querySelectorAll` is the more efficient solution.  Also ironically ID's pollute the global, so your `getElementByName` I would say was the better option.  But of course the best options is `querySelectorAll`

Comment: Somehow querySelectorAll did not work. I still do not know why. I am a bit surprised myself. May be due to some other glitch in the code. Hopefully will figure that out soon.